# NavMeshAgent.SetDestination Y axis problem

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im trying to create simple movement AI for GameObjects.

Each GameObject has `NavMeshAgent`

```
Vector3 destination = new Vector3(Random.Range(-walkArea, walkArea), 0, Random.Range(-walkArea, walkArea));
navAgent.SetDestination(destination);
```

That's what im trying to do. But my baked ground not flat, there could be Y axis up to 30-40.

So if there mountains around GameObject he just gets stuck and can't climb over.

What can i do about it? If i just `navAgent.Move(destination)`, everything works fine. GameObject teleports on X-Z position without worrying about Y axis.

How i can do same thing but with `SetDestination`?

Answer (score 1):

I found solution.

In main `GameObject` i created `empty gameobject` with `NavMeshAgent`.

```
Vector3 destination = new Vector3(Random.Range(-walkArea, walkArea), 0, Random.Range(-walkArea, walkArea));
navDestinationObject.Move(destination);
navAgent.destination = navDestinationObject.transform.position;
```

`navDestinationObject` gets right Y axis on `.Move`, then we just move main `GameObject` to `navDestinationObject` position.

But i think there must be better solution...

Comment: Your answer is technically correct by I think there would be a huge performance issue and it's not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Get the ground `y` by casting a `Ray` where `groundLayerMask` is the `LayerMask` of your ground to prevent misbehave.

```
public void WalkTo(Vector3 position)
{
    Physics.Raycast(position + Vector3.up * 64, Vector3.down, out RaycastHit hit, 128, groundLayerMask);
    position.y = hit.y;
    navAgent.SetDestination(position);
}
```

So we cast a Ray from 64 units above the position to find the ground y and then set it manually. (The RaycastHit is struct so if there is no hit, y will be 0.)